# JOptionPane getValue method

Tags: java, string, swing, joptionpane

I recently started studying Java in college. And in my online test, which is allowed to search, I had a doubt about the method getValue available in the class JOptionPane. Is it true that this method returns an object of class String? If not, why? What kind of object this method returns? Please answer me. Thank you.

Comment: How about consulting [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)?

Comment: please to read [Oracles tutorial about JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: I consulted the Javadoc. The problem is that I do not understand.

Comment: please to click to the JOptionPane tag bellow your question, isn't this question aksed a few times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the JOptionPane and the value that was put there to be selected. If the program gives the user the choice between several `Strings` like (choose: "dog", "cat"...) then you can expect a `String` when calling the `getValue()` method.

*But* be careful, actually the `getValue()` only returns an object from the `class` `Object` and *not* a `String`.  `Object` is *the mother of all classes*, and a `JOptionPane` can hold anything you want (String, Integer, Images other JOptionPanes...) so the method `getValue()` can't really be sure of what kind of class it is returning. That's why it is returning an object of the `class` `Object`.

If you are sure that the JOptionPane contains a `String` then you could use it like this:

```
   String myString = (String) myJOptionPane.getValue();
```

if you are not 100% sure, test the result first:

```
   if( myJOptionPane.getValue() instanceOf String){
       String myString = (String) myJOptionPane.getValue();
   }
```

Now if you are wondering why your question got voted down: you may want to google those questions first. The first way to look is in this [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). For example here is the description of the [JOptionPane.getValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#getValue%28%29). Don't get confused about the complex looking docs. They will give you the correct answer to everything you want to know about how methods and classes work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply GameDroids. The problem is that the teacher did not provide a program in the test. He only asks: is it true or false that the method getValue available in JOptionPane class returns an object of class String?

Comment: well then it is clear (as the Java Docs describe): the getValue() method returns an object of the class `Object` and *not* of the class `String`

Comment: (String)myJOptionPane.getValue( ) makes sense never.

myJOptionPane.getValue( ).toString( ) will return the same String if getValue( ) is a String -- see the javadoc for String.toString( ) -- and won't throw a ClassCast Exception if it's not.

Comment: @gerardw true, `something.toString` won't throw an Exception, but then again it might return something useless like `java.lang.Object@702d2da4`. One should still test before using the result. So I guess it's a matter of taste, to either test `instanceOf` and use `.toString()` or cast the Object to String and catch an expected ClassCastException. Anyway, nice to see someone's still contributing to old posts :)